# Passing a variable from pipeline to a dataflow in azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following setup in ADF and I would like to pass a variable which has been set in Set variable activity to my data flow activity. I tried creating parameter, but I am unable to do so. Can someone explain me how it is done??

As you see I am unable to get $token1 value in my source option in the dataflow.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done it in a correct way, this is how we add pipeline variables to the Data flow.

I have tried from my end the same way and it worked fine for me.

1. Create parameter in data flow.

[image]

2. Pass the value of data flow parameter from pipeline dataflow settings as below:

[image]

3. In Dataflow source options, open the **expression builder** to add dynamic content and select the data flow parameter created.

[image]

4. I created a string variable at the pipeline level and passed it to the data flow string parameter. So in the Authorization value, it is shown as 'abc' to indicate it is **string**.

[image]

5. Data preview of source:

[image]

**Note**: Make sure you are selecting the correct parameter from the expression builder. I see that you have created a parameter as a string but when the parameter is added in the value it is showing as 'Any'. Delete and recreate the parameter/header to refresh any changes.

Comment: no, its not coming.. in expression builder.. i have tried multiple times. pleaseshare at what level have you created the parameter $token1

Comment: Please check my updated answer with additional snips of creating data flow parameters and passing the value from pipeline.

Comment: this is the error I get in the dataflow , other two steps worked fine and the token generated .
""StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Source 'source1'Parameter 'token1'(Line 8/Col 10): Parameter value for token1 missing","Details":""}"

Comment: parameter is of type string

Comment: Are you able to select the parameter in the expression builder? And is it working fine when you give the token directly instead of passing the parameter?