# Azure Data Factory Copy Data Mapping with Blob URL column

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I'm using the `Copy Data` activity from `Microsoft Azure Data Factory` for mapping JSON file attributes in my storage account (source) to MySQL database columns (sink).

**Question:**
Is it possible to get the Blob URL's within Copy Data from the JSON files and send it to my database? I know it's possible to get the file name in the source tab with "`$$FILEPATH`", but I'd like to get the complete URL.

Comment: is your SQL DB on the cloud or on premise?

Comment: @SallyDabbah in Azure Database for MySQL

Comment: is your blob storage Url dynamicly changing ? or is it a constant value ? 
also, is your pipeline triggered by event ?

Comment: @SallyDabbah it is constant but can dynamicly change in the future. The pipeline has lastmodified event and is checking every 5 minutes the source

Comment: NO, my question is : is your blob storage changes (like u write to different container / dataset etc) if its constant you can add an activity (set variable) and add it to your data.

Comment: @SallyDabbah it is constant, how can I add an activity for this?

Answer (score 0):

ok since its constant value , you can add it as a column to your json Data and write it into SQL DB

Here is a quick demo that i created :

1. created a dataflow activity
2. in Dataflow activity, added a json file as a source
3. flattened the json (you have to flatten the json in order to write it into SQL DB because you cant write a complex data type to SQL Db)
4. added a derived column 'BlobUrl', here i mapped a new column and added a string value to the data. (see screenshot attached below) you can ingest here a variable instead of a constant value , please check it out here : [Passing a variable from pipeline to a dataflow in azure data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019999/passing-a-variable-from-pipeline-to-a-dataflow-in-azure-data-factory)
5. saved the result in SQL DB as a sink

**DataFlow Activities:**

[image]

**Derived Column Activity:**

[image]